# tail -f command stopped working

Tags: server

I am completely new to the Linux world so this might be painful all you all and I apologize up front.

I've managed to setup an Ubuntu server as a syslog collector.  It's been collecting logs from my Cisco Meraki device.  Up until today, I was able to run the "tail -f filename" command to see the logs come in live.  However, today, when I run the command, it gives the following lines:

```
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopping irqbalance daemon...
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopped Write warning to Azure ephemeral disk.
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopped Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog omiserver[24804]: /opt/omi/bin/omiserver: stopped server
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopped Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopping D-Bus System Message Bus...
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopping OMS Audit data collection daemon...
Apr 21 23:03:49 LinuxSyslog systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
```

and it just kind of sits there.

I have tried the following: restart the machine and restore the vm but neither helped.  I have no idea what else to do.

Can someone help please?

Thanks
Kit

Comment: Images of text are actually *harder* to read than the text being added.  I simply applied proper formatting and then removed your image link because you already have the text.

Comment: How did you determine that it is `tail -f` that is not working - rather than something related to the logging / log collection itself?

Comment: @steeldriver, due to my lack of knowledge in Linux, the only think I know is that tail -f is not returning the same result as yesterday.  I don't really know what is or is not working.  I do know that the file that I am tailing has reach the size of 2GB and my gut says this maybe the problem.

Comment: update: I have sorted this out.  I cleared the syslog file and this fixed the problem.  tail -f now allows me to see the logs coming in live again.